# Difference between 感知器 and 検知器?

Tags: word-choice

This [page](https://www.shoubousetubi.com/entry/netukemuri/miwakekata) mentions:

- 熱感知器
- 煙感知器
- ガス検知器

The first two devices are "感知器" while the third one is a "検知器". What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of gas, it seems that devices that can display the concentration of a certain type of gas tend to be called 検知器, and sensors that just detect the existence of gas tend to be 感知器.

[This page](https://www.bousai1.jp/html/page46.html) clearly distinguishes 炎感知器 and 炎検知器, and the difference seems to lie in whether the device has been certified by the authority (感知器) or not (検知器). But this does not seem to be a widely accepted distinction.

Overall, there seems to be no fundamental distinction between the two, and they are used simply according to the convention of each field.

Comment: As an additional comment, one could ask a similar question in English -- _"What is the difference between a_ 'detector' _and a_ 'sensor'_?"_ -- where "detector" seems closer to 検知器, and "sensor" seems closer to 感知器.